# SQL:selecting rows matching certain criteria in a specific field

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a situation where i need to select row from DB table which depends on the values in of the columns.

```
Project    Version     Status

MSS           3         active
MSS           2         active 
MSS           1         complete 
RIL           3         active
RIL           2         active  
RIL           1         active
DT            2         complete
DT            1         complete
```

A project is considered complete only if all its versions are complete. That means when status column has 'complete' in all occurrence of same project in the project column of the table.

How can  select only those projects which are complete?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select project
from MyTable
group by project
having count(*) = sum(case when status = 'complete' then 1 else 0 end)
```

Comment: you were missing your from line, but I edited that in for you

Comment: @ZdravkoDanev and Matt Busche this query works, that's what i wanted. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable
WHERE Project IN
(SELECT Project FROM MyTable WHERE Status = 'complete')
```

Comment: I disagree. My query will pull in any row where the Project column is equal to the Project column of a row where the Status = complete

Comment: Okay, I misunderstood what he needed. But you're misunderstanding my query. WHERE Status = 'complete' is not equivalent to my query. My query would pull 5 rows from his sample data. Yours will only pull 3.

Comment: I don't really follow about pulling 5 rows. Ideally the result should be only row i.e the project DT

Comment: Again, I misunderstood the requirements. I thought that any project that had 'complete' in one row met the requirements. My fault for reading wrong.